# How to display array values in select option using map in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display the values of an array in `<option>` tag in react js. So far I have failed.

```
<select>
  {
    op.map(value => (<option key={value} value={value}>{value}</option>))
  }
</select>
```

op is an array. op = 1,2,3. I got the array op like this:

```
for (let i=0; i<Math.ceil(response.data.length/end); i++) {
   op[i] = i+1;
}
```

When I inspect is see only this:

```
<select></select>
```

Comment: the code shown looks ok. you might need to check other things like, does the op contains some calls. or show more code to debug

Comment: Could you print `op` array after the for loop to check if it has values indeed?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the  (select) example

`Math.ceil(response.data.length/end);` needs to be replaced according to your needs.

##### If you need to make an ajax call do it like:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [selOption, setSelOption] = useState(1);

  const [op, setOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //make ajax call here.

    //set this on success of the ajax call
    /*axios.get().then(()=>{
         /here.
    }) 
    */
    let o = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      o[i] = i + 1;
    }
    setOptions(o);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        value={selOption}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSelOption(e.target.value);
        }}
      >
        {op.map((value) => (
          <option key={value} value={value}>
            {value}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      Selected:{selOption}
    </div>
  );
}
```

##### Simple snippet for demo

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [selOption, setSelOption] = useState(1);

  let op = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    op[i] = i + 1;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App"><select
        value={selOption}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSelOption(e.target.value);
        }}
      >
        {op.map((value) => (
          <option key={value} value={value}>
            {value}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      Selected:{selOption}
    </div>
  );
}
```